# Android Skype call happens only if Skype is running in background

Tags: android, skype

I am calling from my Android app using Skype on button click. Below is the code that launches the Skype intent:

```
Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(uri.toString());
Intent myIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED", skypeUri);
myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

The first time this runs, it simply launches the Skype app without calling. When I start Skype in background, it calls the number. I want the user to call the number every time, not from second time onwards, but right now the Skype call happens only if Skype is already running in the background.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I'm experimenting with a workaround of launching skype before making the call if it's not already running, but it would be great to fix the original problem. Thanks for posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to initiate skype calls, and it works ok for me (calls are initiated every time):

```
Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);

myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
myContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

The uri should look something like this:
 skype:skype_contact?call

See the msdn article here: [Skype URI tutorial: Android apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745884.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to initiate skype calll as mentioned below which is taken from my GitHub repository [Skype-Call-Demo](https://github.com/Joisar/Skype-Call-Demo). you can download it as well.

**Code :**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Context mContext;
    private EditText etRecepient;
    private Button btnSkypeCall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        mContext=this;
        etRecepient = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRecepient);
        btnSkypeCall = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSkypeCall);
        btnSkypeCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                skypeCall(etRecepient.getText().toString(), mContext);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private static void goToMarket(Context ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider");
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
          myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          ctx.startActivity(myIntent);

          return;
    }

    private static boolean isSkypeClientInstalled(Context ctx) {
        PackageManager myPackageMgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
          try {
            myPackageMgr.getPackageInfo("com.skype.raider", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
          }
          catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return (false);
          }
          return (true);
    }



    private static void skypeCall(String name, Context ctx) {
        try {
            if (!isSkypeClientInstalled(ctx)) {
                goToMarket(ctx);
                return;
              }

/*          Intent skype_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
            skype_intent.setClassName("com.skype.raider","com.skype.raider.Main");
            skype_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            skype_intent.setData(uri); 
*/            
            Intent skype_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            Uri uri=Uri.parse("skype:"+name+"?call&video=true");
            skype_intent.setData(uri);
            ctx.startActivity(skype_intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("SKYPE CALL", "Skype failed", e);
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT :**

Give it a try, I'm not sure.

I have replaced

```
                Uri uri=Uri.parse("skype:"+name);
```

with

```
                Uri uri=Uri.parse("skype:"+name+"?call&video=true");
```

**Reference :**

[Explicit Skype URI](http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference#uriCallAudioImplicit)

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP and this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DamianHelme: it is working fine for me.can you tell me what exactly happens when you execute it?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I get the symptoms describe in the original post, "The first time this runs, it simply launches the Skype app without calling. When I start Skype in background, it calls the number."

I down-voted your answer because the technique you describe is the standard way to launch a Skype call, it does not address the particular anomaly that was the subject of the question. Please say if if you think that was too harsh a reason to down-vote.

Comment: @DamianHelme: Yup. I think the downvote is obviously harsh as I have atleast tried to help.IMHO instead of downvote,you could discuss the thing and we may try to solve it together.